# Can't connect to EventHubs with Kafka Client

Tags: c#, apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I have an event hubs instance with a “test” eventhub.

I can connect to this and publish messages with the native client "Azure.Messaging.EventHubs"

However when I try to connect with the Confluent.Kafka (v1.1.0) client I get

> “Unknown error (after 21286ms in state CONNECT)”
> %3|1655301022.374|ERROR|rdkafka#producer-1|
> [thrd:sasl_plaintext://my-event-hub-namespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093/bootstra]:
> 1/1 brokers are down

I'm setting the producer config, and creating producer as below

```
var config = new ProducerConfig
{
    BootstrapServers = "my-eventhub-namespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093",
    SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocol.SaslSsl,
    SaslMechanism = SaslMechanism.Plain,
    SaslUsername = "$ConnectionString",
    SaslPassword = "Endpoint=sb://my-eventhub-namespace.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=MySharedAccessKey==",
};

using (var producer = new ProducerBuilder<long, string>(config).SetKeySerializer(Serializers.Int64).SetValueSerializer(Serializers.Utf8).Build())
{
```

Any ideas as to where I'm going wrong?

---

Update :
When connecting with the native client it's connecting using WebSockets, so it's probably networking/firewall issue.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: I used this example [confluent](https://www.confluent.io/blog/build-cross-platform-kafka-applications-using-c-and-dotnet-5/) and [github](https://github.com/confluentinc/WikiEdits/blob/master/Program.cs), but you have the similar config, so config is normal I suggest. I think you need to check that azure kafka don't demand write IP-address, because you get “Unknown error (after ...ms **in state CONNECT**)”. If you plan to use only Azure Cloud for Kafka, so use "Azure.Messaging.EventHubs" package as default.

Comment: @Bushuev: Thanks, but I can connect form the same IP using the eventhubs client library, so I don't think whitelisting is it.

Comment: If you run a test-netconnection xxxx.servibus.windows.net -port 9093 does it succeed ? 
Could be something in your network blocking just the Kafka port

Comment: @Jdresc, Thanks, but I'm not using the default Kafka port (9092), I'm specifically using the EventHubs port (9093) for the broker (as per the documentation)

Comment: @BinaryWorrier Can you try creating a topic's(eventhub in azure) Shared Access Signature(SAS) and replace that in `SaslPassword`  and then try?

https://nielsberglund.com/2022/01/02/how-to-use-kafka-client-with-azure-event-hubs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to try

- Firewall check for EH endpoint. Make sure the client can connect to my-eventhub-namespace.servicebus.windows.net:9093.
- Try with a namespace-level connection string if you used entity-level SAS.

Comment: Thanks, that I can connect with the EventHubs Api means I can get through the firewall. What do you mean by _namespace-level_ connection string? The connection string I'm using is for the EventHubs "instance", not for a single EventHub/Topic.

Comment: . . . and when using the native client it's connecting with websockets, it's probably a networking/firewall issue, thanks.

Comment: AMQP client goes through port 5671 or over 443 if websockets is enabled.

Comment: @BinaryWorrier what was the root cause of the issue ? Not having network access to port 9093 or not having the proper connection string ?

Comment: @greg the port wasn't open on the service, and I didn't have access to open it through Azure. To be honest I can't remember the details and I haven't looked at that project in 9 months or so.